# Self expanding Code via Preprocessor directives

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'd like to define a preprocessor statement like this:

```
#define INSERT_NOPS(num) .......
```

and somewhere in my code

```
INSERT_NOPS(10);
```

Now I want my preprocessor to roll out the following code:

```
asm volatile("nop");
asm volatile("nop");
asm volatile("nop");
asm volatile("nop");
asm volatile("nop");
```

How can I realise this? (0<=num<100000)

I don't want to any if/else statements inside my Macro.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a better solution without using Boost:

```
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC optimize ("unroll-loops")
#pragma GCC optimize ("O2")
void nops() {
 int i = 0;
 for(; i < 10 ; i++) {
   asm volatile("nop");
 }
}
#pragma GCC pop_options

int main(void) {
  nops();
}
```

To compile with:

```
gcc -c -o test.o -O3 test.c
```

Having a look at the disassembly:

```
objdump -d test.o

test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <nops>:
   0:   90                      nop
   1:   90                      nop
   2:   90                      nop
   3:   90                      nop
   4:   90                      nop
   5:   90                      nop
   6:   90                      nop
   7:   90                      nop
   8:   90                      nop
   9:   90                      nop
   a:   c3                      retq   

Disassembly of section .text.startup:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   2:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  7 <main+0x7>
   7:   f3 c3                   repz retq
```

Comment: But how do you invoke this for 10 nops one call and 20 nops another call?

Comment: You would need two different functions. Those functions could automatically be expanded via macros. Calling those functions parameterized makes no sense as I want the nop's to be statically compiled as atomar instructions.

Answer (score 3):

This is far from trivial to roll by hand. Have a look at the [Boost Preprocessor Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html), which works for C as well as C++. [`BOOST_PP_REPEAT`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/repeat.html) does what you want:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>

#define INSERT_NOP(z, n, data) asm volatile("nop");
#define INSERT_NOPS(num) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(num, INSERT_NOP, )

INSERT_NOPS(10)
```

Proof:

```
$ g++ -E test.cc
[...]
asm volatile("nop"); asm volatile("nop"); asm volatile("nop"); asm volatile("nop"); asm volatile("nop"); asm volatile("nop"); asm volatile("nop"); asm volatile("nop"); asm volatile("nop"); asm volatile("nop");
```

Comment: Well, actually i don't want to use Boost or any third party libraries / definitions... I'll have a look inside BOOST_PP_REPEAT. Thanks!

Comment: That file alone is 825 lines. You might find that it borders on insanity.

Comment: I know. But Code size / Compile Time doesn't matter in my case. I don't want to have side effects triggered by some loops. It's a very ciritical system in time.

Comment: "Side effects triggered by some loops"? This is a preprocessor library. There are no side effects. My demo above shows that it expands exactly to the code you want, and nothing else besides.